# OpenCV - JPEG compression on arm/android phone doesn't result the right image

Tags: c++, opencv, android-ndk

I have written an android app which uses OpenCV to manipulate with images. I'm using the below code to write a cv::Mat object to JPG file.

```
cv::imwrite("<sd card path>/img.jpg", <some mat object>);
```

I do see the image being saved on my sd card, however, the colors are not right. It has some bluish color all over the image.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: Probably the color space changed to RGB, OpenCV default is BGR. Just use [cvtColor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above comment by Haris resolved this issue. I modified the code to change the color space as below:

```
cv::Mat mat;

// Initialize mat
cv::cvtColor(mat, mat, CV_BGR2RGB);
cv::imwrite("<sd card path>/img.jpg", mat);
```

I was able to see the right image being saved with this.